# Frida pass hookDetected and isJailBroken methods on Android

Tags: react-native, hook, jailbreak, frida

We are working on a react native app that uses `"jail-monkey": "^2.7.0"`, and at the initialisation of the app we check if the device is jail broken or in case there are any hooking methods attached to our app with `JailMonkey.hookDetected() || JailMonkey.isJailBroken()` so we can throw a warning message to the user, but the problem is that just by doing that, a pentest team achieved to use the Android app without getting the warning message using Frida.

**My question**: *should we add something else beside that? Is there any known issue where Frida can penetrate these methods?*

Thank you for your time!

Comment: If you are attacking a specific app you can just decompile it and hook the methods that check for the installed hooks. Real hooking protection systems first obfuscate and harden the app so that a hooking framework has problems to attach to the app process and thus can not install the hooks.